# Can't load relative config file using ConfigParser from sub-directory

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
my_program/
       foo.py
       __init__.py # empty
       conf/
          config.cfg
          __init__.py
```

In foo.py I have this:

```
import sys 
#sys.path.append('conf/')
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read( 'conf/config.cfg' )
```

In `conf/__init__.py` I have

```
__all__ = ["config.cfg"]
```

I get this error in `foo.py` that I can fix by giving the full path but not when I just put `conf/config.cfg` but I want the relative path to work:

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError
```

which actually means that the file can't be loaded (so it can't read the section).

I've tried commenting/un-commenting `sys.path.append('conf/')` in `foo.py` but it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Paths are relative to the *current working directory*, which is usually the directory from which you run your program (but the current directory can be changed by your program [or a module] and it is in general *not* the directory of your program file).

A solution consists in automatically calculating the path to your file, through the `__file__` variable that the Python interpreter creates for you in `foo.py`:

```
import os
config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'conf', 'config.cfg'))
```

Explanation: The `__file__` variable of each program (module) contains its path (possibly relative to the current directory when it was loaded, I guess—I could not find anything conclusive in the Python documentation—, which happens for instance when `foo.py` is imported from its own directory).

This way, the import works correctly whatever the current working directory, and wherever you put your package.

PS: side note: `__all__ = ["config.cfg"]` is not what you want: it tells Python what symbols (variables, functions) to import when you do `from conf import *`. It should be deleted.

PPS: if the code changes the current working directory between the time the configuration-reading module is loaded and the time you read the configuration file, then you want to first store the *absolute* path of your configuration file (with `os.path.abspath()`) before changing the current directory, so that the configuration is found even after the current directory change.

Comment: Thank you.  Same problem though I'm afraid: 

`import os`
`import ConfigParser`

`config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()`
`config.read( os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'conf', 'config.cfg' ) )`

raises the same error as before.  I have removed the `__all__ = ["config.cfg"]` too

Comment: If I print the path then it correctly says `./conf/config.cfg` which is strange!

Comment: Can you try with the updated version of the answer? it uses an absolute path instead of a possibly relative one.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work :).  It now prints `/conf/config.cfg`.

Comment: From what directory do you run your program and/or import my_program.foo?

Comment: `foo.py` is a daemon.  Inside `foo` is class (`Foo`) that is instantiated from within the same file (is this okay?).  `Foo` is inherits from http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/ hope that helps?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Then you have to handle the fact that the current working directory is changed  during instantiation (there is a `os.chdir("/")`) in the class you link to. Adding details to your question seems important, at this point: when do you instantiate `Foo` (which changes the current working directory) compared to your configuration reading? etc. My current guess is that you should get the file path *before* instantiating `Foo` (you can store it in a variable and use it later, if need be). Does this work?

Comment: _all_ = ["config.cfg"] in _init_.py is not required. Answer works pefectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `os` package in python for importing an absolute or relative path to the configuration file. Here is a working example with the relative path (we suppose that `config.ini` in the folder name `configuration` that is in the subdirectory of your python script folder):

```
import configparser
import os

path_current_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path_config_file = os.path.join(path_current_directory, 'configuration', config.ini)
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(path_config_file)
```

Answer (score -6):

Just load the path from a Variable and why so complex?

```
 from configparser import ConfigParser

 prsr=ConfigParser()
 configfile="D:\Dummy\DummySubDir\Dummy.ini"
 prsr.read(configfile)
 print(prsr.sections())
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as `my_program` (from the question) is moved, so this is not a practical solution, in this case.