# configparser not working in Python 3.4, NoSectionError but works fine in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, python-3.4, configparser

I worked on a Python 3.4 script in PyCharm 4.5. (repo: https://github.com/Djidiouf/bbot )
In it, I used `import configparser` without any problem for retrieving some values in a config.cfg:

```
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
server = config.get('bot_configuration', 'server')
channel = config.get('bot_configuration', 'channel')
botnick = config.get('bot_configuration', 'botnick')
port = config.getint('bot_configuration', 'port')
```

Now, I want to deploy it on a Debian 8.1 server. On that server, I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 versions installed.

But when I ran the script on the machine, I have the following issue:

```
djidiouf@linuxserver:/home/djidiouf# /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/djidiouf/bbot/bbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 1116, in _unify_values
    sectiondict = self._sections[section]
KeyError: 'bot_configuration'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/djidiouf/bbot/bbot.py", line 25, in <module>
    import modules.steam  # Contains specific Steam-Valve related functions
File "/home/djidiouf/bbot/modules/steam.py", line 13, in <module>
    import modules.connection
File "/home/djidiouf/bbot/modules/connection.py", line 37, in <module>
    server = config.get('bot_configuration', 'server')
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 754, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 1119, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'bot_configuration'
```

I made a lot of research on Internet about that but I didn't find anything valuable. Some people made mention about a corrupt config.cfg file but mine is a LF EOL file with UTF8 without BOM as needed. I also recreated it again with vi on the machine.

I also tried to install configparser with pip (even if, if I understand it well, it's now build-in in Python 3) : `pip3 install configparser` But when I do that, I have the following error:

```
djidiouf@linuxserver:/home/djidiouf# sudo pip3 install -v configparser
[sudo] password for djidiouf:
Downloading/unpacking configparser
Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/configparser/configparser-3.5.0b1.tar.gz#md5=d60ca2c714acb4adaf5818c6a1ffd78b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/configparser/), version 3.5.0b1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/configparser/configparser-3.5.0b2.tar.gz#md5=ad2a71db8bd9a017ed4735eac7acfa07 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/configparser/), version 3.5.0b2 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Using version 3.3.0r2 (newest of versions: 3.3.0r2, 3.3.0r1, 3.2.0r3, 3.2.0r2, 3.2.0r1)
Downloading configparser-3.3.0r2.tar.gz
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/configparser/configparser-3.3.0r2.tar.gz#md5=dda0e6a43e9d8767b36d10f1e6770f09 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/configparser/)
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-v7av3db7/configparser/setup.py) egg_info for package configparser
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        import distutils.core
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 18, in <module>
        from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/config.py", line 7, in <module>
        from configparser import ConfigParser
    File "/tmp/pip-build-v7av3db7/configparser/configparser.py", line 397
        _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>

    import distutils.core

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 18, in <module>

    from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/config.py", line 7, in <module>

    from configparser import ConfigParser

File "/tmp/pip-build-v7av3db7/configparser/configparser.py", line 397

    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")

                                        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-v7av3db7/configparser
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-v7av3db7/configparser

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Here is a config example, I just changed the values and rename the file accordingly to config.cfg :

```
[bot_configuration]
server = your.irc.server.com
channel = ##your_channel
botnick = bbot
port = 6667
admins = You,Him
```

https://github.com/Djidiouf/bbot/blob/master/config_example.cfg

Finally, I just want to say that everything is working on PyCharm 4.5, I just made a `git clone`, rename the config_example.cfg, change the values, tried to run the script with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I had some inconsistency about running the script. When I was in another folder than my script, nothing worked but when I was in it, it worked. Perhaps because the config file is shared and used in the main script and in a module.
In fact it's due to the need to have an absolute path in `config.read('/some/path/file.cfg')`

Finally, I find that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800583/3301370

---

So here is the solution in the case of config.cfg being on the project root directory */config.cfg* :

*/bbot.py*

```
import os
config.read(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'config.cfg'))
```

However, as the config file is shared and used in the main script and in a subpath, module, a correct path must be set for the sub module too:

*/modules/connection.py*

```
import os
config.read(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..', 'config.cfg'))
```

It works fine in PyCharm because when you hit the run button for your script, it runs it with the path of the project. The fact that having a relative path for both `config.read()` statements worked only because of that.

The problem with installing configparser with pip is unrelated to that specific problem and can be ignore in that case as configparser is a built-in library in Python3.

Comment: *your config file cannot be found, pass the full path and I bet it will work*

Answer (score 2):

The install error is from `_KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")`, that  is causing a syntax error as the `ur` prefix is not supported in python3, pip is trying to instal a python2 package.

Your first error is a keyError `'bot_configuration'` which is not because of not having configparser installed, `configparser` is part of the standard library.

The `bot_configuration` `KeyError` is because python cannot find your config file, if you use `config.read('foobar')` in pycharm you will see the exact same output

Comment: In PyCharm where I developed my script, my python interpreter  is 3.4.3 without any doubt.

Comment: @Djidiouf, exactly that is my point,  `ur` is not supported in python3, it should simply be `r`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is going wrong in my code or my setup and why it's working well on PyCharm and not on my server?

Comment: The error is not because of `configparser` not being installed, the errors are all coming from the original KeyError

Comment: Thank you for your explanation about my pip3 error. But how can I use configparser on python3?

Comment: @Djidiouf, I edited the answer, your config file cannot be found, pass the full path and I bet it will work

Comment: In the meantime, I reinstalled python3.4 and it's working now. I think with my installation of configparser with pip, I messed things in Python 3.4 builtin configparser as pip tried to install a python2 package as you warned me. Thx! (can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation myself, sorry)